# How action performing on Activity reflect changes in home widget button (text/images)

Tags: android

I have an app's that have a widget button at home, now I want that If I press button from my app's activity then the widget button text should be changed. Activity and Widget both are from same app's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send an `Intent` from your app and evaluate it in `OnReceive` of your app widget:

app:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ACTION_MYWIDGET_CHANGE);
sendBroadcast(i);
```

widget:

```
String action = intent.getAction();
if (action.equals(ACTION_MYWIDGET_CHANGE))
{...}
```